# QtCreator: "Cannot open include file: 'windows.h'"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, qt-creator

I’m new to Qt, so I decided to start from running some tutorials (from QtCreator).
I wanted to compile a project from tutorial 2 “Creating a Qt Quick Application Using Qt Quick Components”, but ended with the below error message:

```
D:\Software\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -nologo -j 8 -f Makefile.Release
  cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t- -O2 -MD -GR -EHsc -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQ_COMPONENTS_SYMBIAN -DHAVE_MOBILITY -DQT_DLL -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -I"..\..\..\Software\QtSDK\Simulator\Qt\msvc2008\include\QtCore" -I"..\..\..\Software\QtSDK\Simulator\Qt\msvc2008\include\QtNetwork" -I"..\..\..\Software\QtSDK\Simulator\Qt\msvc2008\include\QtGui" -I"..\..\..\Software\QtSDK\Simulator\Qt\msvc2008\include\QtDeclarative" -I"..\..\..\Software\QtSDK\Simulator\Qt\msvc2008\include" -I"..\..\..\Software\QtSDK\Simulator\QtMobility\msvc2008\include\QtSystemInfo" -I"d:\Software\QtSDK\Simulator\QtMobility\msvc2008\include\QtMobilitySimulator" -I"..\Tut1\qmlapplicationviewer" -I"..\..\..\Software\QtSDK\Simulator\QtMobility\msvc2008\include" -I"..\..\..\Software\QtSDK\Simulator\QtMobility\msvc2008\include\QtMobility" -I"..\..\..\Software\QtSDK\Simulator\Qt\msvc2008\include\ActiveQt" -I"release" -I"..\Tut1" -I"." -I"..\..\..\Software\QtSDK\Simulator\Qt\msvc2008\mkspecs\win32-msvc2008" -Forelease\ @C:\Users\113010~1\AppData\Local\Temp\qmlapplicationviewer.obj.2328.0.jom
 qmlapplicationviewer.cpp
 d:\software\qtsdk\simulator\qt\msvc2008\mkspecs\win32-msvc2008\../win32-msvc2005/qplatformdefs.h(67) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory
 Copying application data... 
 2 File(s) copied
```

I have a Visual Studio 2008 Professional. Qt Creator seems to recognize it well, so such an error should never appear I think.

I also wanted to change the tool set from Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 9.0 (x86) to MinGW (it also appears in the dialog when clicked Manage button), but the combo box is inactive.

I don't know what to do.

Comment: Do you find a `windows.h` somewhere in your visual studio directory?

Comment: Yes: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\SmartDevices\SDK\Smartphone2003\Include

Comment: When you change your toolset, you're going to need to recompile all of the Qt DLLS under ming.

Answer (score 1):

in Qt Creator, Tools--Options, Build&Run, Kits, choose a kit and edit its attributes, change the Compiler from "Microsoft Windows SDK ..." to "Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 9.0 (x86)".

Answer (score 0):

You may have to install the [Windows SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=3138) if you have not done yet.

Comment: I have v6.0A. Will try with the newer version.

Comment: I've installed SDK v7.0, but it gave no effect. After that I've added **MinGW** package to QtSDK and now I can run every example without any problem. Thanks anyway.